# Compare two lists and add empty rows to each list when not matched

Tags: c#

I'd like to compare two string lists and put in empty spaces where a match doesn't occur.

**Edit**

So, if this is the original list:

```
| List #1 | List #2 |
|-------------------|
|  ID: 1  |  ID: 1  |
|-------------------|
|  ID: 3  |  ID: 2  |
|-------------------|
|  ID: 4  |  ID: 4  |
|-------------------|
|  ID: 5  |  ID: 6  |
|-------------------|
|         |  ID: 7  |
|-------------------|
|         |  ID: 8  |
|-------------------|
```

I'd like the result to be something like this:

```
| List #1 | List #2 |
|-------------------|
|  ID: 1  |  ID: 1  |
|-------------------|
| [Empty] |  ID: 2  |
|-------------------|
|  ID: 3  | [Empty] |
|-------------------|
|  ID: 4  |  ID: 4  |
|-------------------|
|  ID: 5  | [Empty] |
|-------------------|
| [Empty] |  ID: 6  |
|-------------------|
| [Empty] |  ID: 7  |
|-------------------|
|  ID: 8  |  ID: 8  |
|-------------------|
```

I know about C#'s Except/Intersect but I am not sure how to put it all together or whether there is a built-in algorithm that would do this.

```
List(string) listOne = new List<string>();
List(string) listTwo = new List<string>();

/*
Items added to list here.
*/

var inListButNotInList2 = listOne.Except(listTwo);
var inList2ButNotInList = listTwo.Except(listOne);

var bothLists = listOne.Intersect(listTwo);

/*
What can I do here for inserting empties into each list?
*/
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: And your expected output?

Comment: @Eser The expected output would be two **new** lists which contain the empty strings where there wasn't a match in the other corresponding list.

Comment: Why not just iterate over both lists and if the items at each index do not match then insert an empty string at that location? No need to use built in functions for this.

Comment: The example you provided is not going to happen, all the blanks will be in one list (except if you're comparing to a third list).
I'd just iterate and set it to whatever I wanted. What is the exact use case for this?

Comment: @GustavoMaloste The use case would be to show the comparison to the end user in an easy to view fashion. So; imagine both lists in alphabetical order and side by side but because there are blanks where otherwise there would be a match then it is easy to see for the user.

Comment: @Tdorno Trying your suggestion out now.

Comment: @ChrisK. If a question is commented like here, then you should think it is not understood well.... In fact, requests are simple. sample inputs and expected output. Can you provide that?

Comment: @Eser I'll provide an example.

Comment: @Eser edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I have understood your intentions here's my solution. I assume that you want to see which values does not appear on both lists and the values that are not present on the other list should be marked as [Empty] (or whatever you want to). This is my solution (it uses simple left join):

```
var allElements = listOne.Union(listTwo).OrderBy(x => x);
var query = from element in allElements
        join second in listTwo on element equals second into step
        from intermediate in step.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select intermediate ?? "[Empty]";
```

The provides snipped computes value for the first list. Replacing listTwo with listOne you get the other result.

Answer (score 2):

Not considering optimizations, but gonna work:

```
var a = new[] { "b", "c", "d", "k", "l", "o" };
var b = new[] { "a", "c", "d",  "l", "o" };
var merged = new List<string>(b).Concat(a.Except(b)).OrderBy(e => e);
var aWithEmpty = merged.Select((e) => a.Contains(e) ? e : "[EMPTY]");
var bWithEmpty = merged.Select((e) => b.Contains(e) ? e : "[EMPTY]");
```