# Compare two lists and add blank space if not a match

Tags: r, bash, awk

does anyone have a solution to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228144/compare-two-lists-and-add-empty-rows-to-each-list-when-not-matched) but in bash or R? I need the same output as this post but I have zero knowledge of C.

In short, I have files with the first file being blast data, and the second  being abundance data. I need to match up the ASVs (identifiers) from the two files so I can match up taxonomy info and the abundance info into one file. There are instances where not every ASV has a blast result, so there will be missing ASVs in the blast data file (file 1). In those cases, I want to insert a blank line so that later when I copy over the taxonomy info, they will match up to the correct ASV in the abundance file (file 2).

List 1 is a set of taxonomy information, list 2 is a list of ASVs and abundance data. Here is my example data and they do contain headers. **Edit** they can be either csv or text files. The example here are for text files.

File1.txt:

```
ASV Percent_Identity    Evalue  Taxid   Title
012a3e401584af45819ba1c4409381bb    99.6    7.61e-124   549 Pantoea agglomerans
6095c6c24ff4e87866804d0806340c71    99.6    7.61e-124   77133   Uncultured bacterium
9f94e24e6e7757238df875434b3207f8    100 1.63e-125   77133   Uncultured bacterium
2654ad4af2207cdca21d16a97ddfeace    100 1.63e-125   77133   Uncultured bacterium
1d8e161787abc1c1dce62b190e1493eb    100 1.63e-125   77133   uncultured bacterium
bed6fb75e90ee410096bef8c0847f46f    99.2    3.54e-122   77133   Uncultured bacterium
```

File2.txt: I saved the identifiers as just a simple list in the order they appear in the abundance file as it is not necessary to copy over the abundance info here.

```
012a3e401584af45819ba1c4409381bb
6095c6c24ff4e87866804d0806340c71
9f94e24e6e7757238df875434b3207f8
2654ad4af2207cdca21d16a97ddfeace
1d8e161787abc1c1dce62b190e1493eb
907b63f00fdcd1a6c51d2e632f8b7fb8
bed6fb75e90ee410096bef8c0847f46f
```

As you will see, `bed6fb75e90ee410096bef8c0847f46f` is not the 6th row but rather the 7th in `file2.txt`, so I would like the output in a new file to be something like:

File3.txt:

```
ASV Percent_Identity    Evalue  Taxid   Title
012a3e401584af45819ba1c4409381bb    99.6    7.61e-124   549 Pantoea agglomerans
6095c6c24ff4e87866804d0806340c71    99.6    7.61e-124   77133   Uncultured bacterium
9f94e24e6e7757238df875434b3207f8    100 1.63e-125   77133   Uncultured bacterium
2654ad4af2207cdca21d16a97ddfeace    100 1.63e-125   77133   Uncultured bacterium
1d8e161787abc1c1dce62b190e1493eb    100 1.63e-125   77133   uncultured bacterium
EMPTY    EMPTY    EMPTY    EMPTY    EMPTY  
bed6fb75e90ee410096bef8c0847f46f    99.2    3.54e-122   77133   Uncultured bacterium
```

Edit: I do not want to the sort these files as they are already in an order that I want to keep.

Comment: At the top you ask for code in R but in the bottom you ask for code in `awk`. Which one do you actually want? In R, you would do a left or right join (depending on how you order the parameters) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: I guess I had no specific preference, I can try R as I've used R a few times but I've also had some people suggest to me to use awk for this type of stuff.

Comment: `diff file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: Import `library(readr); library(dplyr)` to start your script, then read the files via `file_1 <- read_csv("path/to/file_1.csv"); file_2 <- read_csv("path/to/file_2.csv")`, and finally join the datasets like so: `result <- data_1 %>% right_join(data_2, join_by(ASV == ASV))`.  The `EMPTY`s in your example will appear as [`NA`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/NA.html)s in `result`.

Comment: I used diff to see the differences but then I would have to manually add the gaps myself no?

Comment: Try `join -a 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`. Unpairables are left empty.

Comment: I don't want to sort the file. They are ordered already and match orders for other files in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, using any awk, may be what you want:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { if (NR==1) print; else a[$1]=$0; next }
    { print ($1 in a ? a[$1] : "EMPTY    EMPTY    EMPTY    EMPTY    EMPTY") }
' file1 file2
ASV Percent_Identity    Evalue  Taxid   Title
012a3e401584af45819ba1c4409381bb    99.6    7.61e-124   549 Pantoea agglomerans
6095c6c24ff4e87866804d0806340c71    99.6    7.61e-124   77133   Uncultured bacterium
9f94e24e6e7757238df875434b3207f8    100 1.63e-125   77133   Uncultured bacterium
2654ad4af2207cdca21d16a97ddfeace    100 1.63e-125   77133   Uncultured bacterium
1d8e161787abc1c1dce62b190e1493eb    100 1.63e-125   77133   uncultured bacterium
EMPTY    EMPTY    EMPTY    EMPTY    EMPTY
bed6fb75e90ee410096bef8c0847f46f    99.2    3.54e-122   77133   Uncultured bacterium
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks so much. It added gaps correctly and when I copied the data over to the abundance file, it lined up perfectly.

Comment: Suggest you enclose the output with tag `none` to avoid the meaningless syntax highlight ?

Comment: @MyICQ meh, people can ignore it if they find the script body being green meaningless. Clicking the `{}` button is faster/easier than typing 3 ticks then `none` before the code then another 3 ticks after it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1{x;s/.*/cat file1/e;P;x}
        G;/^(\S+)\n.*(\1[^\n]*).*/{s//\2/p;d}
        s/^[^\n]+\n//;s/\S+/EMPTY/g;P;d' file2
```

On the first line of the second file, slurp the first file into memory and print its heading line too.

For each line in the second file append the copy of the first file and either:

- Match the key from the second file to the first and print the first files line.
- Or, remove the key and replace by the headings whose headings have been replaced by `EMPTY` and print that.

Answer (score 0):

What your attempting to do looks like using SQL parlance file2 LEFT JOIN file1 ON file2.1stcolumn = file1.1stcolumn, if you are okay with limiting yourself to CSV files and allowed to install tools at your machine you might use [`csvjoin`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvjoin.html) from csvkit following way, let `file1.csv` content be

```
012a3e401584af45819ba1c4409381bb,99.6,7.61e-124,549,Pantoea agglomerans
6095c6c24ff4e87866804d0806340c71,99.6,7.61e-124,77133,Uncultured bacterium
9f94e24e6e7757238df875434b3207f8,100,1.63e-125,77133,Uncultured bacterium
2654ad4af2207cdca21d16a97ddfeace,100,1.63e-125,77133,Uncultured bacterium
1d8e161787abc1c1dce62b190e1493eb,100,1.63e-125,77133,uncultured bacterium
bed6fb75e90ee410096bef8c0847f46f,99.2,3.54e-122,77133,Uncultured bacterium
```

and `file2.csv` content be

```
012a3e401584af45819ba1c4409381bb
6095c6c24ff4e87866804d0806340c71
9f94e24e6e7757238df875434b3207f8
2654ad4af2207cdca21d16a97ddfeace
1d8e161787abc1c1dce62b190e1493eb
907b63f00fdcd1a6c51d2e632f8b7fb8
bed6fb75e90ee410096bef8c0847f46f
```

then

```
csvjoin --delimiter , --snifflimit 0 --left --columns 1 file2.csv file1.csv
```

gives output

```
012a3e401584af45819ba1c4409381bb,99.6,7.61e-124,549,Pantoea agglomerans
6095c6c24ff4e87866804d0806340c71,99.6,7.61E-124,77133,Uncultured bacterium
9f94e24e6e7757238df875434b3207f8,100,1.63E-125,77133,Uncultured bacterium
2654ad4af2207cdca21d16a97ddfeace,100,1.63E-125,77133,Uncultured bacterium
1d8e161787abc1c1dce62b190e1493eb,100,1.63E-125,77133,uncultured bacterium
907b63f00fdcd1a6c51d2e632f8b7fb8,,,,
bed6fb75e90ee410096bef8c0847f46f,99.2,3.54E-122,77133,Uncultured bacterium
```

Explanation: I inform `csvjoin` that delimiter is `,` and there is no need to sniff delimiter and instruct it to do LEFT at 1st column of `file2.csv` and `file1.csv`. Observe that where there is not data empty string is used to convey that (common way whilst using CSV files) and there is `907b63f00fdcd1a6c51d2e632f8b7fb8` in output.

*(tested in csvjoin 1.4.0)*